# GnuTLS source code modifications seems to be ignored

Tags: c, compilation, gnutls

I've forked the GnuTLS repo, cloned my copy and made some modifications to the source code (I'm trying to add a new cipher) but my modifications seems to be ignored.

At first I've done the preparation steps

```
./bootstrap
./configure
```

Make my changes, build and install:

```
make -j$(nproc)
make -j$(nproc) install
```

Included the necessary headers in my C program just to see if my modifications have effect:

```
#include <gnutls/gnutls.h>
#include <gnutls/crypto.h>
```

But they don't. Just to make sure, I've "broken" the `gnutls_cipher_init()` function in `lib/crypto-api.c` by returning a custom error at the beginning:

```
int gnutls_cipher_init(gnutls_cipher_hd_t *handle,
               gnutls_cipher_algorithm_t cipher,
               const gnutls_datum_t *key, const gnutls_datum_t *iv)
{
    return gnutls_assert_val(MY_CUSTOM_ERROR);
    api_cipher_hd_st *h;
    int ret;
    const cipher_entry_st *e;
    bool not_approved = false;
.
.
.
```

But it seems like none of my modifications are taking any effect, just like the file wouldn't even be compiled.

I've tried to re-`./configure` and rebuild and reinstall many times, just to make sure everything works without errors, but none of this worked.

Even if I've done something really stupid implementing my cipher, the `return` of the beginning of the function shouldn't be ignored.
Also, just to make sure the file is compiled, I've messed it up (ex. deleted a `;`) just to provoke some errors, and the errors appeared, so I think the file is compiled.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I've tried to uninstall it, rebuild and install again:

```
make -j$(nproc) uninstall
make -j$(nproc)
make -j$(nproc) install
```

But that's not the solution.

Comment: Where is it being installed? How are you linking to it?

Comment: This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow, as presented. It is too broad. Diagnosis should proceed by digging into the procedures in detail: Is the executable file actually using the library? Does the object code in the library contain the modifications? Does the `make` command issue a compilation command? Does that compilation command use the right source files? Where are the object files put? Does the link command use those object files? And so on. It is your responsibility to dig into those details and figure out what is going on. Stack Overflow is for narrow, specific questions.

Comment: For a typical Unix-like system, the default installation path for an autoconf'ed package is `/usr/local`.  Your OS's install of gnutls is probably in `/usr` instead, and your compiler likely searches `/usr` for headers and libraries first.  So you'll need to build your app with appropriate `-I` and `-L` flags to specify the directories where your new installation can be found.

Comment: Your program is probably getting dynamically linked to the original library installed by the package manager. You can run `ldd /path/to/your/program` to check the pathnames of the dynamic libraries it is linked to.